# Vue app only renders API data correctly in local dev, not in production build (using vuex, axios, and parcel)

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, parceljs

I've got a basic client-side rendered vue app that fetches [a json array from an API endpoint](https://groceries-vue-api.glitch.me/get) and renders data from each array item as a list item in an ordered list.

The data renders as expected when I'm developing locally, using `parcel index.pug` to spin up my local dev environment. Here's a screenshot of the expected ordered list as shown in my local dev environment at `localhost:1234`:

[image]

However, the data does not render as expected when I build for production (using `parcel build index.pug`). Here's a screenshot of the unexpected behavior in production mode (which you can see live online at https://errands.netlify.com/):

[image]

Notice that the production version knows the fetched API data is an array with a length of 6 (because it renders out 6 empty `<li>`s), but for some reason the production version does not know the data inside each array object.

The full source code for this app is here, https://github.com/brianzelip/groceries-vue.

The main relevant code (the axios call to the API, which updates the vuex store, then renders out the ordered list) lives in [`TheGroceryForm.vue`](https://github.com/brianzelip/groceries-vue/blob/master/src/components/GroceryForm/TheGroceryForm.vue), which is also included here:

```
<template>
  <form action="/submit" method="POST">
    <ol class="list-reset border rounded">
      <li class="item" v-for="item in allGroceryItems" v-bind:key="item._id">
        <GroceryFormItemEditLink/>
        <GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput :slug="item.slug"/>
        <GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel :slug="item.slug" :name="item.name"/>
        <GroceryFormItemQtySelector :slug="item.slug"/>
        <GroceryFormItemStoresSelector
          :stores="item.stores"
          :slug="item.slug"
          :defaultStore="item.defaultStore"/>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

import GroceryFormItemEditLink from './GroceryFormItemEditLink.vue';
import GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput from './GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput.vue';
import GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel from './GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel.vue';
import GroceryFormItemQtySelector from './GroceryFormItemQtySelector.vue';
import GroceryFormItemStoresSelector from './GroceryFormItemStoresSelector.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  components: {
    GroceryFormItemEditLink,
    GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput,
    GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel,
    GroceryFormItemQtySelector,
    GroceryFormItemStoresSelector
  },
  computed: {
    allGroceryItems() {
      return this.$store.state.allGroceryItems;
    },
    allGroceryItemsCount() {
      return this.$store.getters.allGroceryItemsCount;
    }
  },
  getters: {},
  created() {
    axios
      .get('https://groceries-vue-api.glitch.me/get')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('axio.get worked! res.data =', res.data);
        console.log(`typeof res.data = ${typeof res.data}`);

        const groceryData = res.data;
        console.log('groceryData =', groceryData);
        console.log(`typeof groceryData = ${typeof groceryData}`);

        const newData = res.data.map(obj => obj);
        console.log('newData', newData);
        return newData;
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log('data from second then() =', data);
        return data;
      })
      .then(data => (this.$store.state.allGroceryItems = data))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR! ->', error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

**Why does the data change when I build my app for production? And how can I change this behavior to get the expected outcome?**

Comment: I cloned your repo and I'm having the same issue when running locally with `parcel index.pug`

Comment: thanks for your effort @yuriy636. But I'm not sure why you're getting 6 blank list items, when I have the data filled in the list items when run locally, as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: @yuriy636 do you get the json data in your browser when going to https://groceries-vue-api.glitch.me/get?

Comment: Yes.We do get json data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using self closing tags.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036

So your `TheGroceryForm.vue` will be

```
<template>
    <form action="/submit" method="POST">
        <ol class="list-reset border rounded">
            <li class="item" v-for="item in allGroceryItems" v-bind:key="item._id">
        <GroceryFormItemEditLink></GroceryFormItemEditLink>
        <GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput :slug="item.slug"></GroceryFormItemCheckboxInput>
        <GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel :slug="item.slug" :name="item.name"></GroceryFormItemCheckboxLabel>
        <GroceryFormItemQtySelector :slug="item.slug"></GroceryFormItemQtySelector>
        <GroceryFormItemStoresSelector
          :stores="item.stores"
          :slug="item.slug"
          :defaultStore="item.defaultStore"></GroceryFormItemStoresSelector>

      </li>
    </ol>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: The official style guide says otherwise ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

Comment: I owe you an apology. I checked out OP's project and applied your changes and it does indeed work. Must be something to do with the bundler and loaders OP is using. There was still a problem with the SVG but I'm sure you've put OP on the right track now

Comment: What a crazy gotcha! I've seen so many self-closing components in tutorials and blog posts. Thanks for your help. You're right about the svg @Phil - but when I apply the above insight to that component, it still doesn't work. I'll have to noodle around a bit more.